# Use of -ing after when

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following sentence grammatical by using **when synthesizing**?
That is, can we use of -ing after when?

> Although it is possible to include material A **when synthesizing**
>   component B, it might make component B unnecessarily harder.

Comment: Yes, it's quite common. When running through the neighborhood, watch out for dogs. Although it is possible to include quotes when writing a short story, it might make the story less original.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with this sentence; it's grammatically correct.  You can use "when + -ing form of a verb as long as this clause matches the subject of the main clause.